# Alfresco: Found 1 integrity violations: The association source type is incorrect

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to create `vncr:sender` node as a child node of `nvcr:senders` node (custom types).

vncr:senders model :

```
    <type name="vncr:senders">
        <title>Courrier senders</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
        <associations>
            <child-association name="vncr:contains_sender">
                <source>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>vncr:sender</class>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>true</many>
                </target>
                <duplicate>false</duplicate>
            </child-association>
        </associations>
    </type>
```

vncr:sender model

```
    <type name="vncr:sender">
        <title>Courrier sender</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="vncr:name_sender">
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                <multiple>false</multiple>
            </property>
            <property name="vncr:email_sender">
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </type>
```

Template instance component

```
    <component>
        <region-id>sender</region-id>
        <url>/components/form?mimeType={mimeType}</url>
        <properties>
            <itemKind>type</itemKind>
            <itemId>vncr:sender</itemId>
            <destination>{destination}</destination>
            <mode>create</mode>
            <submitType>json</submitType>
            <showCaption>true</showCaption>
            <showCancelButton>true</showCancelButton>
            <htmlid>{htmlid}</htmlid>
        </properties>
    </component>
```

when I submit the form I have the following response

> "message" : "06040016 Found 1 integrity violations:\nThe association
> source type is incorrect: \n   Source Node:
> workspace://SpacesStore/c7ccd6bc-4e0c-4662-8660-58d263a81e4d\n
> Association: Association[
> class=ClassDef[name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder],
> name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}contains, target
> class={http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base, source
> role=null, target role=null]\n   Required Source Type:
> {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder\n   Actual
> Source Type: {http://www.vneuron.com/model/courrier/1.0}senders",
>
> "exception" : "org.alfresco.repo.node.integrity.IntegrityException -
> 06040016 Found 1 integrity violations:\nThe association source type is
> incorrect: \n   Source Node:
> workspace://SpacesStore/c7ccd6bc-4e0c-4662-8660-58d263a81e4d\n
> Association: Association[
> class=ClassDef[name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder],
> name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}contains, target
> class={http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base, source
> role=null, target role=null]\n   Required Source Type:
> {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder\n   Actual
> Source Type: {http://www.vneuron.com/model/courrier/1.0}senders",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a `"cm:content"` under a `"cm:content"`, I do not think that is possible. Error message tries to convey this too, by saying that it expects `"cm:folder"`.

Note, you can associate two `cm:content` nodes, just not with parent/child association.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the problem, I changed the parent of `cnvr:senders` to `cm:folder` and it works.